# How to capture key presses in a Cocoa application that runs in the background?

Tags: cocoa, quartz

I am making a small utility that will detect when the numlock key is pressed.

I am currently able to execute a script to control numlock with a tool called Spark, by Shadow Lab:
https://www.shadowlab.org/softwares/spark.php

So, I know that it is possible.

In fact, there are applications such as Quicksilver and many others that do this, so it must be possible (despite obvious security concerns).

How can I achieve this?

From googling, I have found suggestions to use `NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown)` as well as Quartz Event Services.

I have tried with NSEvent and it does not seem to capture the keyDown events, and there is not much documentation on the best way to use Quartz Event Services.

To be clear, my application does not have a window and I would like to be able to capture key-down events system-wide.

Can somebody please advice the best way to capture a keypress?

Thanks!

Comment: (And yes, I do see the irony of flagging this as a duplicate of that ;-) )

Comment: nice, thank you for finding that. Worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm curious how some applications, like 1Password, don't require accessibility to be set to get system-wide key-presses. Maybe, because it's with a modifier key?

Comment: I don't know much about 1Password, so I can't speak to how it's implemented, sorry.